# Swift Compiler Messing around

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am having this problem with swift and it is extremely frustrating:

I need to use `SKAction.followPath(path:, speed: )` :

```
var moveaction = SKAction.followPath(path:path, speed: POINTS_PER_SEC)
```

When I try to use this Xcode says:

> Missing argument for parameter 'orientToPath' in call

If I add "orientToPath: true", it gives me

> Extra argument 'orientToPath' in call

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, because I am only getting this in one file (followPath works perfectly everywhere else).
I already tried deleting the line and rewriting it, even cutting the entire code and pasting it again. I get the exact same error.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First validate that `path` is a `CGPath`, and `speed` is a `CGFloat`. I'll assume that's correct.

The problem is Swift is picky about named parameters. You need to remove `path:`.

```
var moveaction = SKAction.followPath(path, speed: POINTS_PER_SEC)
```

This method has the signature `class func followPath(_ path: CGPath, speed speed: CGFloat) -> SKAction`. The way you called the method expected it to have the signature `class func followPath(path path: CGPath, speed speed: CGFloat) -> SKAction`. The difference between `_ path: CGPath` and `path path: CGPath` makes the methods look different to the compiler.

Comment: I had already removed path:, sorry... If the parameters were of a wrong type I would get a different error.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the contents of the file to a new one, now it works... Must be some sort of bug.